# Pandas reverse of diff

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have this code and I am trying to reverse the process to get identical values in B3 and C3 after differencing A colums.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.random.randint(0, 10, 10)})
df['C'] = df['A']
df['B'] = df['A'].diff(periods=1)

df['B2'] = df['B'].shift(-2)
df['B3'] = np.where(df['B2'] > df['B'], 1, -1)

df['C2'] = df['C'].shift(-2)
df['C3'] = np.where(df['C2'] > df['C'], 1, -1)
```

Here is the result :

```
   A  C    B   B2  B3   C2  C3
0  4  4  NaN -7.0  -1  1.0  -1
1  8  8  4.0  5.0   1  6.0  -1
2  1  1 -7.0 -3.0   1  3.0   1
3  6  6  5.0 -2.0  -1  1.0  -1
4  3  3 -3.0  6.0   1  7.0   1
5  1  1 -2.0 -4.0  -1  3.0   1
6  7  7  6.0  0.0  -1  3.0  -1
7  3  3 -4.0  1.0   1  4.0   1
8  3  3  0.0  NaN  -1  NaN  -1
9  4  4  1.0  NaN  -1  NaN  -1
```

How would I reverse the differentiated B3 column to get identical values to C3 ?

Comment: That depends on which columns can be used for the computation. I assume columns `C3`, `A` or `C` are not available?

Comment: The cumsum function is the inverse of diff. Does that solve the problem?

Comment: All columns are known so I know the values of C3, A and C. Cumsum doesn't seem to work in this case.

Comment: @ZacharyTeste - Just take `C3`. You have the values already.

Comment: I wrote to fast. I don't know C3. I'm trying to generate C3 from B3.

Comment: If only `C3` is missing and you have `A`: repeat the computation you did to get `C3`. You already computed this.

Comment: It seems like this problem is either trivial (because you can recompute C3 from A) or unsolvable (because the conversion of B2 -> B3 destroys data necessary to produce C3.) This makes me think that I don't understand your question. Can you clarify your question?